# Can a player survive suffocation with a Periapt of Wound Closure?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, character-death, breathing

The [Periapt of Wound Closure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/periapt-of-wound-closure)'s description says

> While you wear this pendant, **you stabilize whenever you are dying at the start of your turn.** In addition, whenever you roll a Hit Die to regain hit points, double the number of hit points it restores.

**Emphasis mine.**

What happens to a PC wearing Periapt of Wound Closure while suffocating? I'd like to transport myself using a Homunculus and a Bag of Holding, but I worry about suffocating during the journey.

**If I put on a Periapt of Wound Closure and enter a Bag of Holding, will I suffocate to death while inside of the bag or will the Periapt keep me alive?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## You would suffocate to death unless it is a short trip.

Bag of Holding:

> Breathing creatures inside the bag can survive up to a number of minutes equal to 10 divided by the number of creatures (minimum 1 minute), after which time they begin to suffocate. [roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bag%20of%20Holding#h-Bag%20of%20Holding)

Suffocating (emphasis mine):

> When a creature runs out of breath or is choking, it can survive for a number of rounds equal to its Constitution modifier (minimum of 1 round). At the start of its next turn, it drops to 0 Hit Points and is dying, and **it can’t regain Hit Points or be stabilized** until it can breathe again. [roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/The%20Environment#content)

Thus, the Periapt of Wound Closure can not stabilize you. You'd have to start making Death Saves after you drop to 0 HP. Unfortunately, three successes can't stabilize you either, so you'd be making Death Saves until you died or could breath.

Note: The [PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) updated the wording of Suffocating to include that you can not be stabilized.

Comment: Damn, missed that in the errata ... 3 words change everything